# Magento SOAP API request always get redirected [Magento 1.9.3.3]

Tags: c#, magento, soap, magento-1.9

I'm developing C# application to communicate with Magento. When I try to login to get Session ID to do stuff. I use C# code below.

My login code

```
using (MagentoService mservice = new MagentoService())
    {    
        loginResponse = mservice.login("admin", "admin123");
    }
```

It always throws me this error

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://admin.mywebsite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : Premature end of data in tag html line 7
```

because my API request gets redirected to the website's homepage every time.

Follow this link for more info of this error: [Cannot login Magento service using C# [Magento 1.9.3.3] Error: Premature end of data in tag html line 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424083/cannot-login-magento-service-using-c-sharp-magento-1-9-3-3-error-premature-en))

Is there any way to stop my API request from getting redirected? Also is it possible to do from client without interfering Magento settings?

Comment: What happens when you manually make request to WSDL url? Is it properly opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the server owner to disable redirect from the API request endpoint URL (`https://admin.mywebsite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/`) and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

On the Magento server side, here is what I had to set in the Apache vhost configuration :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.magento\.biz$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/
RewriteRule ^ https://magento.biz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

It seems to be a known Magento bug with 2 parameters that's collides :

- Auto-redirect to Base Url
- Use Custom Admin URL with a subdomain